# Почему некоторые символы не отображаются на других компьютерах, и можно ли это исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Написала код, используя символы ♥☺♦... и так далее (Которые получаются путем нажатия alt + "цифра"). При запуске кода на ноутбуке все прекрасно отображается и работает. После отправки кода на другой компьютер и его запуска все эти символы стали отображаться в виде вопросительного знака. С чем это связано? И можно это как-то исправить, не устанавливая ничего на сам компьютер (грубо говоря, модифицируя сам код)?

Comment: А как запускается скрипт в обоих случаях в каких системах? в командной строке или в IDE? Во втором случае просто вывод не поддерживает символы unicode.

Comment: 1) В какой кодировке сохранен файл? 2) Какие именно "цифры" вводились для получения символов?

Comment: если интересует более глубокий ответ, можите послушать https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VY95vgOROo8&list=PLlb7e2G7aSpQhNphPSpcO4daaRPeVstku&index=5&t=0s

Answer (score 0):

> все эти символы стали отображаться в виде вопросительного знака. С чем
> это связано?

Очевидно, что это связано с тем, что на этих двух компах у вас используются разные кодовые страницы. Скорее всего, на одном cp1251, а на другом utf8.